# If IE then include file [A] else include file [B]

Tags: php, javascript, smarty

I have page for which I want to load **different content** for **different browsers**.

**Example :**

```
IF Internet explorer

{include file="/content1.tpl"}

ELSE if any other browser

   {include file="/content2.tpl"}

{/if}
```

**Content1.tpl** & **Content 2.tpl** are two different files having their respected **Html & CSS.**

How can I achieve this using Javascript OR php ?

**Thanks,**

- Mandar

**EDIT**

What I want is, **IE** to completely **neglect content2.tpl**

& **Mozilla** or Other to completely **neglect content1.tpl**

Comment: **Don't rely on the User Agent String**!!! Very bad approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Work :

```
<!--[if IE]>
{include file="/content1.tpl"}       
<![endif]-->

<![if !IE]>
{include file="/content2.tpl"}   
<![endif]>
```

Look [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 10):

**Don't use PHP for this.** You are much safer doing this at browser level, preferably using [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html). You [cannot trust the HTTP_USER_AGENT](http://johnbokma.com/mexit/2004/04/24/changinguseragent.html) as it is very easy for forge/change so you cannot confidently (and therefore should not) make decisions based on its value. Stick to one `.tpl` file and either include a specific stylesheet based on a conditional comment or add additional markup using these comments. For example you can add additional markup like this and then target accordingly:

```
<html>
<body>
<!--[if IE 6]><div id="ie6"><![endif]-->
... main content here
<!--[if IE 6]></div><![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What I want is, IE to completely neglect content2.tpl

& Mozilla or Other to completely neglect content1.tpl

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the `get_browser()` PHP function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Note that USER AGENTS can be forged, so you can't rely on this 100%.

Answer (score 2):

in PHP you could look at the superglobal named $_SERVER. There, under the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` key you will find the browser.

That will be computed server-side, using PHP and Smarty.

In Javascript, use [this](http://www.codehelp.co.uk/html/jquery.html)

in HTML you could use [this syntax](http://www.unintentionallyblank.co.uk/2006/09/19/if-internet-explorer-then-do-something-else-a-how-to/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<!--[if IE]>
{include file="/content1.tpl"}       
<![endif]-->

<comment>
{include file="/content2.tpl"}   
</comment>
```

Internet Explorer ignores the `<comment></comment>` tags as though they were standard comments, but all other browsers read them like normal code. This is great for hiding non-IE code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<script type = " javascript" >
if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
{
    /*
      do something
    */
}
else
{
    /*
      do something else
    */
}
</script>
```